# Gps heading iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am a beginner in programming ios,
I would like to get the direction using the gps,
I know compass's functions, but this is not what i'm looking for, i'm looking for a function or a formula who gives my displacement's direction (heading).
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html) should help out!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to register for updates with [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)'s heading methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you tilo,
details here :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    double direction = newLocation.course;

}
```